# Making a msgbox show status during a nested loop?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've come across a bug in my Macro where while it's running through a list of input data it just suddenly stops but also still runs in dev mode.

```
For LngRow = 2 To Wksht.Range("A" & Wksht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 1) <> "" Then
            IE.Navigate Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 1)

            'This loops waits for IE to be ready
            Do Until (IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete") And (Not IE.busy)
                DoEvents
            Loop

            'grabs address
            For Each c In Array("vk_sh vk_bk", "_Xbe")
                dd = ""
                dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(c)(0).innerText
                If Len(dd) > 0 Then
                    Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 3) = dd
                    Exit For

            MsgBox "Working on", , dd 'doesn't work

                End If
            Next

            'grabs business name
            For Each b In Array("kno-ecr-pt kno-fb-ctx _hdf")
                bb = ""
                bb = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(b)(0).innerText
                If Len(bb) > 0 Then
                Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 9) = bb
                Exit For
              End If
           Next

           'Grabs phone number
           For Each a In Array("_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv")
                aa = ""
                aa = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(a)(0).innerText
                If Len(bb) > 0 Then
                Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 10) = aa
                Exit For
              End If
           Next

        End If
    Next
```

What it does is go through IE pages of addresses and pulls info from them, each for loop is for a different piece of info all contained in one bigger loop (nested).

What I tried to make it do is display a msgbox saying "Working on (dd)", so I could see what address it was processing at that time so I could see what kind of addresses it hangs on. And then of course to make it disappear. I did this by putting "MsgBox "Workin on", , dd" but that didn't work. I do not know where to put it in the context of nested loops.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your `MsgBox` is located in the code after an `Exit For`, so will never be executed.

Comment: Yeah I've moved it out, it works now but only displays AFTER the loop has processed an address and it has a button which needs to be pressed before it will run again.

Comment: As @YowE3K is suggesting, what if you put it right before the `Exit For`?

Comment: or use `Application.Statusbar` instead

Comment: You are running this in excel right? Write each URL to a new line in an excel sheet. (you could also include execution time next to it)

Comment: Debug.Print dd perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try msgbox after if condition.

```
         For Each c In Array("vk_sh vk_bk", "_Xbe")
            dd = ""
            dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(c)(0).innerText
            If Len(dd) > 0 Then

               MsgBox "Working on", , dd 'doesn't work

                Wksht.Cells(LngRow, 3) = dd
                Exit For

            End If
        Next
```